# If $\frac{a+b}{b+c}=\frac{c+d}{d+a}$ then..

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, fractions

If $\frac{a+b}{b+c}=\frac{c+d}{d+a}$ then

(A) $a=c$

(B) either $a=c$ or $a+b+c+d=0$

(C) $a+b+c+d=0$

(D) $a=c$ and $b=d$

I solved $\frac{a+b}{b+c}=\frac{c+d}{d+a}$ and got $a(a+b+d)=c(c+b+d)$ and so I thought that (A) is the correct option. But the correct answer is (B).

I'm how $\frac{a+b}{b+c}=\frac{c+d}{d+a}$ if $a+b+c+d=0$. Please help.

Comment: Question. Are you sure you copied (B) correctly from your source?

Comment: Yes sir I' sure.

Comment: (B) is the correct answer as it is written. I'm not sure how you got your solution, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a small error when you solved the equation.  You should have gotten

$$a(a+b+d)=c(c+b+d)$$

Note the $c$ in $c+b+d$ on the right.  Can you take it from there?

**Added after the OP's edit**:  Now write the above as

$$a((a+b+c+d)-c)=c((a+b+c+d)-a)$$

which becomes

$$(a-c)(a+b+c+d)=0$$

Comment: Sorry sir that was a typing mistake, I have edited it.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** we get by cross multiplication
$$a^2+ab+ad+bd=bc+bd+c^2+dc$$from here we get
$$ab-bc+ad-cd+a^2-c^2=0$$
or
$$(a-c)(a+b+c+d)=0$$

Comment: Best and simplest answer... Vote up!

Comment: your are welcome waiting for your next problem

Answer (score 3):

If $a+b+c+d=0$, then $(a+b)=-(c+d)$ and $(b+c)=-(a+d)$, therefore $$\frac{a+b}{b+c}=\frac{-(c+d)}{-(a+d)} = \frac{c+d}{a+d}$$

provided that we don't divide by zero anywhere.

Comment: The if-then $\rightarrow$ is correct even without qualification. If the first equation holds, one of the two in (B) also must. If the implication were reversed $\leftarrow$, you would need to specify the inequalities. (+1, though.)

Comment: @DivergentQueries The statements $b+c \neq 0$, $a+d \neq 0$ have been removed.

Comment: Sir thank you for showing me how I was supposed to do the problem when the options are given.

Answer (score 0):

On the right hand side, you should have $c(c + b + d)$, not $c(a + b + d)$. Check your work on that again.

It might be easier if you leave things fully expanded, then bring all terms to one side and then factor at the end.

Comment: We noticed the same thing at about the same time.  The OP says it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo#Comment_on_the_proof),  $$\dfrac{a+b}{b+c}=\dfrac{c+d}{d+a}=\dfrac{1(a+b)+1(c+d)}{1(b+c)+1(d+a)}$$

$\implies(a+b+c+d)\{a+b-(b+c)\}=0$