# If $a+b:b+c = c+d: d+a$, prove that $a=c$ or $a+b+c+d=0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a+b:b+c = c+d: d+a$, prove that $a=c$ or $a+b+c+d=0$.

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{a+b}{b+c}=\dfrac{c+d}{d+a}$

$\Rightarrow (a+b)(a+d)=(b+c)(c+d)$

$\Rightarrow a^2+ad+ab+bd = bc+bd+c^2+cd$

$\Rightarrow a(a+b+d)=c(b+c+d)$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{a}{c}=\dfrac{b+c+d}{a+b+d}$

Now $\dfrac{a}{c}+1=\dfrac{b+c+d}{a+b+d}+1$, and $\dfrac{a}{c}-1=\dfrac{b+c+d}{a+b+d}-1$

Or $\dfrac{a+c}{c}=\dfrac{a+2b+c+2d}{a+b+d}$, and $\dfrac{a-c}{c}=\dfrac{-a+c}{a+b+d}$

Divide those two equations:

$\dfrac{a+c}{a-c}=\dfrac{a+2b+c+2d}{-a+c}$

$\Rightarrow (c+a)(c-a)=(a-c)(a+2b+c+2d) \Rightarrow -(c+a)(c-a)=(c-a)(a+2b+c+2d)$

$\Rightarrow -a-c=a+2b+c+2d \Rightarrow 2a+2b+2c+2d = 0 \Rightarrow a+b+c+d=0$

Question: Does this mean $a=c$ is wrong? Or is there a way to prove that too? I'm a bit confused because I just calculated and stumbled around and got $a+b+c+d=0$ merely by serendipity. Thanks for the help.

Comment: At one step you divide by $a-c$, which would be zero, if $a=c$, hence you need to make a case distinction there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $\frac{a+b}{b+c}=\frac{c+d}{d+a}$ then..](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368787/if-fracabbc-fraccdda-then) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Ba%2Bb%7D%7Bb%2Bc%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7Bc%2Bd%7D%7Bd%2Ba%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24a%2Bb%2Bc%2Bd%3D0%24&p=1). Note that, in your approach, for example, the line $\frac{a}{c}=\frac{b+c+d}{a+b+d}$ assumes that $c\neq 0$ and $a+b+d\neq 0$. Instead, I considered myself the approach used in this [answer](/a/1368795), which I believe is simplest & easiest ...

Comment: (cont.) There are also several duplicate AoPS threads, e.g., [If, then...](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c5h551106p3199295) , [Deduction from a fraction](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c5h571083p3354744), (with both indicating the problem is from problem #$32$ of the $1964$ AHSME), etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Question: Does this mean $a=c$ is wrong? Or is there a way to prove that too?

The easiest way to realize it works is to let $a=c$ and observe that (provided the denominators are nonzero) it reduces to the equation $1=1$.

Alternatively, note that the step where you divide the equations,
$$\begin{align*}
&\dfrac{a+c}{c}=\dfrac{a+2b+c+2d}{a+b+d} \text{ and } \dfrac{a-c}{c}=\dfrac{-a+c}{a+b+d}\\
&\implies
\dfrac{a+c}{a-c}=\dfrac{a+2b+c+2d}{-a+c}
\end{align*}$$
is assuming that $a \ne c$ (because if $a=c$, then you're dividing by zero).

So, much as when one solves $x^2 = x$ by dividing by $x$, you have an implicit pair of cases: one where $x \ne 0$ (and hence division is permissible) and one where $x=0$ (which needs to be checked via alternative means) -- or in this case, one where $a \ne c$ (giving you the result you derived) and one where $a=c$ (which needs to be checked if it holds, but it does trivially hold).

Answer (score 0):

By *Fraction Arithmetic*,  you have :

$$
\begin{align}&\dfrac{a+b}{b+c}=\dfrac{c+d}{d+a}\\\\
\color{#c00}{\iff} &\dfrac{a-c}{b+c}=-\dfrac{a-c}{d+a}\end{align}
$$

which implies $\thinspace a=c\thinspace $ or $\thinspace a+b+c+d=0\thinspace .$

Indeed, if $\thinspace a≠c\thinspace $, then dividing both side of the equality by $\thinspace a-c\thinspace $, you get :

$$\dfrac {1}{b+c}=\dfrac {1}{-(d+a)}$$

This leads to $\thinspace b+c=-(d+a)\thinspace $ or $\thinspace a+b+c+d=0\thinspace $ .

---

$\color{#c00}{\rm \bf{Fraction \thinspace \thinspace arithmetic }}$

$\thinspace \dfrac AB=\dfrac CD \thinspace $ holds iff, when :

$$\thinspace \frac{A-B}{B}=\frac {C-D}{D}\thinspace .$$

Comment: @ronaldchristenkkson assuming that $a≠c$, then multiplying both sides of the equality $\dfrac {1}{a-c}$ you get $b+c=-(d+a)$ which yields $b+c+d+a=a+b+c+d=0.$